# Use sed to replace all backslashes with forward slashes(doubles too)

Tags: regex, bash, sed

I want to be able to use sed to take an input such as:

```
\\servername\folder\folder\folder
```

To

```
//servername/folder/folder/folder
```

seen this question here but the answer "echo 'C:\foo\bar.xml' | sed 's/\///g'" provide this string: "/servername/folder/folder/folder" (one forward slash is missing).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

sed seems a bit overkill since you want only transliterate a single character. You can use tr that is designed for this specific task:

```
echo '\\servername\folder\folder\folder' | tr '\\' '/'
```

As @Kent notices it, sed has the transliteration command y:

```
echo '\\servername\folder\folder\folder' | sed 'y#\\#/#'
```

Comment: +1 for the `tr`, however sed is not useless for this task, apart from `s` cmd can do it, for single char, sed has `y` cmd, which is more suitable for this task.

Comment: @Kent: you are right. I always forget that sed has other commands.

Comment: this doesnt work, output is /servername/folder/folder/folder, that is, one slash is missing. just like i mentioned in question.

Comment: @Osher: that is strange I obtain the good result. You have probably used double quotes in place of single quotes somewhere.

Comment: You are correct!! :))) until now I was always using double quotes for echo string. thank you!!

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
s='\\servername\folder\folder\folder'
sed 's~\\~/~g' <<< "$s"
//servername/folder/folder/folder
```